# Is there a Python package to convert InChi to molecular structures?

Tags: structural-biology

I am looking for a python package that can convert InChi keys (e.g.SGNXVBOIDPPRJJ-UHFFFAOYSA-N) to molecular structure or SMILES strings. Can I do that with RDKit?

The key comes from: https://www.metabolomicsworkbench.org/databases/refmet/refmet_latest.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, RDKit can be used, however, if you installed it with `conda` it will not work out of the box for inChi key fetching. You can either spend some time installing the missing bit or use something else. It is not like Mol2 support in RDKit, which shouldn't be used, it is just not worth the bother.

I would suggest [PubChem's RESTFul API](https://pubchemdocs.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug-rest).

Say

```
 import requests
 ethanol = 'LFQSCWFLJHTTHZ-UHFFFAOYSA-N'
 r = requests.get(f'https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/inchikey/{ethanol}/property/CanonicalSMILES/JSON').json()
 smiles = r['PropertyTable']['Properties'][0]['CanonicalSMILES']
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Though I get {'Fault': {'Code': 'PUGREST.BadRequest',
  'Message': 'Missing structure string',
  'Details': ["An argument for 'inchi' must be provided in the URL path or POST data"]}} when I run your code.

Comment: Sorry for that. I fixed the typo by using your code. But I am glad it works now!

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified Matteos answer:

```
import requests
def get_smiles_from_inchikey(inchikey):
    r = requests.get(f'https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/inchikey/{inchikey}/property/CanonicalSMILES/JSON').json()
    return r['PropertyTable']['Properties'][0]['CanonicalSMILES']

inchikey = 'SGNXVBOIDPPRJJ-UHFFFAOYSA-N'
get_smiles_from_inchikey(inchikey)
```